# Removing elements dynamically

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, canvas

I have drawn some lines dynamically inside a `canvas`. How do I delete them using `C#` ?
I tried:

```
for (int ix = this.canvas1.Children.Count - 1; ix >= 0; ix--)
if (this.canvas1.Children[ix] is Line) this.canvas1.Children[ix].Dispose();
```

but system is not accepting `Dispose` as a method.

Comment: note that Dispose is part of IDisposable interface for releasing resources - not removing from canvas ... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try to loop over all items through the Canvas.Children collection and remove or make invisible items you want to delete.

Comment: you can set Opacity or Visibility attribute to make item invisible

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution of problem

```
for (int ix = this.canvas1.Children.Count - 1; ix >= 0; ix--)
      {
          if (this.canvas1.Children[ix] is Line) this.canvas1.Children.RemoveAt(ix);
            }
```